# Why can`t I seem to assign values to my constant fields?

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am using c# and trying to assign logical (not null) values to my custom type constant fields. here is how.

```
public class Types_of_Accuracy{
1   public const Types_of_Accuracy Decimal_Places=Type_of_Accuracy(false);
2   private bool SD;
3   public const Types_of_Accuracy Significant_Digits=Type_of_Accuracy(true);
4   private static Types_of_Accuracy Type_of_Accuracy(bool Significant_digits){
5       Types_of_Accuracy TA=new Types_of_Accuracy();
6       TA.SD=Significant_digits;
7       return TA;
8   }
}
```

When I try compiling. I get these errors.

- Line 1|'Types_of_Accuracy.Decimal_Places' is of type 'Types_of_Accuracy'. A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null. (CS0134)
- Line 3|'Types_of_Accuracy.Significant_Digits' is of type 'Types_of_Accuracy'. A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null. (CS0134)

So far, my favorite solution is to replace the code above, with the code below.

```
public class Types_of_Accuracy{
1   static Types_of_Accuracy(){
2   Decimal_Places.SD=false;
3   Significant_Digits.SD=true;
4   }
5   public const Types_of_Accuracy Decimal_Places=null;
6   private bool SD;
7   public const Types_of_Accuracy Significant_Digits=null;
}
```

Any improvements will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A suggestion: Drop the underscores and use [Capital Camel Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Constant fields must be initialized with constant values.
- And they have to be of a value type, or string, or be initialized with null.

`Types_of_Accuracy` is a class (reference type), and you're trying to initialize the constants with method calls, which are not constants. As a workaround, you can declare the fields as `static readonly` instead:

```
public static readonly Types_of_Accuracy Decimal_Places = Type_of_Accuracy(false);
public static readonly Types_of_Accuracy Significant_Digits = Type_of_Accuracy(true);
```

It's not exactly the same as a constant: using the value of a readonly field will actually read the field at runtime, while using a constant will replace it with its value at compile time. But in most cases, this difference doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

A `const` is a compile time constant, reference types cannot be assigned at compile time so you need to use a readonly static field instead to assign them at runtime

```
public class Types_of_Accuracy{
   public static readonly Types_of_Accuracy Decimal_Places=Type_of_Accuracy(false);
   private bool SD;
   public static readonly Types_of_Accuracy Significant_Digits=Type_of_Accuracy(true);
   private static Types_of_Accuracy Type_of_Accuracy(bool Significant_digits){
       Types_of_Accuracy TA=new Types_of_Accuracy();
       TA.SD=Significant_digits;
       return TA;
   }
}
```